# Connection using client id and secrete key in java with oauth2 google api

Tags: java, google-oauth

I am new java developer.Trying to connect using client id and secret key.But still i got one exception like that.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:98)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:76)
    at GmailQuickstart.authorize(GmailQuickstart.java:133)
    at GmailQuickstart.main(GmailQuickstart.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

### Source Code

```
 GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("me");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception stack trace states that it was unable to find class `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`

Ensure that the [javax servlet jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api) is present in the classpath.

Also, similar exception has been answered at [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892475/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-http-httpservletrequest)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and include the **javax.servlet.jar** into your [java path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse), [download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxservletjar.htm)