# Error in ServletFileUpload#parseRequest(request) with tomcat 10

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, multifile-uploader, apache-commons-fileupload, tomcat10

Working on a simple file upload program. I had to use jakarta.servlet.* classes as I am using Tomcat v10. I am getting compile time error on parseRequest(request) line.

### Code :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServletFileUpload sf = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
        try {
            List<FileItem> multifiles = sf.parseRequest(request);
            
            for(FileItem i : multifiles) {
                i.write(new File("C:/Users/Luffy/Documents/FileUploadDemo/"+i.getName()));
            }
            response.getWriter().print("The file is uploaded");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        response.getWriter().print("The file is uploaded");
    }
```

---

The error is as below:

**The method parseRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) in the type ServletFileUpload is not applicable for the arguments (jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)**

I searched a lot on google but couldn't find a solution.

Please suggest a workaround or possible solution. Thanks in advance.

This is my first post in Stack overflow. So ignore my mistakes if any :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use the [`ServletFileUpload`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html) class from `commons-fileupload`, which doesn't work with a `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`. The library must be adapted to work with Servlet 5.0 classes.

Fortunately since Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 8.0) `multipart/form-data` requests can be parsed by the servlet. You just need to:

- Add a [`@MultipartConfig`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/annotation/multipartconfig) annotation to your servlet,
- Use [`HttpServletRequest#getParts()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getParts()):

```java
try {
    final Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
    for (final Part part : parts) {
       part.write("C:/Users/Luffy/Documents/FileUploadDemo/"+part.getSubmittedFileName());
    }
    response.getWriter().print("The file has been uploaded successfully.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Upload failed.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    try {
        Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
        for (Part part : parts) {
            System.out.println(part.getSubmittedFileName());
            part.write("c:/images/"+part.getSubmittedFileName());
        }
        
        response.getWriter().print("The file has been uploaded successfully.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.sendError(response.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Upload failed.");
    }
    
}
```

I also implement this it is working perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).