# Tomcat 10 Webapp migration - servletFileUpload.parseRequest error

Tags: java, tomcat, migration

I am migrating Webapps from a `Tomcat 9` to a `Tomcat 10` environment.
I am using the `Eclipse IDE`.

Below is a part of the code that provokes errors:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
[...]
DiskFileItemFactory diskFileItemFactory = null;
ServletFileUpload   servletFileUpload   = null;
List<FileItem>      fileItemsList       = null;

    diskFileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    servletFileUpload   = new ServletFileUpload(diskFileItemFactory);
        
    fileItemsList = (List<FileItem>) servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);
```

The errors are linked to this last line.

I get the errors:

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest. Fix the build path then try building this project
The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

As part of this migration, I had to replace `javax.servlet` with `jakarta.servlet` in the Webapps Java source code and replace the .jars `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar` and `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar` with the `jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0.jar` and `jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-2.0.0.jar` .jars.

Can you help me solve these errors?

====== EDIT ======

Piotr P. Karwasz's answer solves my problem.

But, instead of adding annotations, which doesn't seem to work for me, I added, in the Webapp `web.xml` file, for the servlets concerned,  the `<multipart-config>` element as shown below:

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>FooServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.bar.FooServlet</servlet-class>    
    <multipart-config>
      <location>/tmp</location>
      <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>    
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/do_foo_servlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in ServletFileUpload#parseRequest(request) with tomcat 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67313127/error-in-servletfileuploadparserequestrequest-with-tomcat-10)

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not answering you earlier but I'm still correcting the code (which works as far as files uploading is concerned). Yes, your answer solves my problem. Thanks. I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`commons-fileupload`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload) library is not and probably will **never** be compatible with Servlet 5.0. Since Servlet 3.0 a similar functionality has been included into the standard (see [section 3.2](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#file-upload)).

To migrate your code to Tomcat 10, you need to:

1. remove `commons-fileupload` from your dependencies,
2. annotate your servlet with [`@MultipartConfig`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/annotation/multipartconfig),
3. replace the call to `ServletFileUpload#parseRequest` with [`HttpServletRequest#getParts`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getParts()):

   ```java
   final Collection<Part> fileItemsList = request.getParts();
   ```
4. since [`FileItem`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html) and [`Part`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/part) have almost the same methods, only minor changes are needed in the remaining code.

Comment: Just note, that it is Collection<Part> not Collection<Parts>