# The ServletFileUpload class has disappeared from version tomcat-embed-core-10.1.0 and following

Tags: java, apache-commons-fileupload, tomcat10

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload class has disappeared from version tomcat-embed-core-10.1.0 and following (This class is present in version 10.0.27), while the others (Commons FileUpload) seem to be present. In addition, the embedded version number of Commons FileUpload is no longer shown.

[image][image][image][image]

I want to upgrade from tomcat-embed-core-10.0.27.jar to tomcat-embed-core-10.1.2.jar

**EDIT #1**

Is it normal that the file is no longer present?

**EDIT #2**

Thanks for your answer. Yes, you are right "*Yes, it's normal that a new version of a software changes, removes, renames any of its implementation.*" the problem in this case, is that the comments in the file "org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.package-info.class" of tomcat-embedded-core versions > 10.0.27 mentions a typical use case that refers to an absent class. (CF below)

[image]

So I wonder, if the absence of this class (org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload) is not a bug?

Comment: ...and your question is? ([ask]) (if it's about your code, it's useful to show your code instead of screenshots of a directory hierarchy)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste my question. which is: Is it normal that the file is not present anymore? I edited my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in ServletFileUpload#parseRequest(request) with tomcat 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67313127/error-in-servletfileuploadparserequestrequest-with-tomcat-10) (Or, to phrase it as direct answer to your question: Yes, it's normal that a new version of a software changes, removes, renames any of its implementation. Very often that means that this functionality might be available somewhere else. Sometimes it's no longer supported. You're lucky that the first condition holds for you

Comment: As you've edited: Check the question that I've marked this as a duplicate: It has the proper solution. And just because the 10.0 documentation refers to something as 10.0.27+, it does not mean that all future versions will have the same APIs implemented. Not necessarily for 10.1, 11.0 or 42.0 - I'd _somehow_ expect it to stay available in 10.0.x, but even if it disappears there, you now know about a standardized alternative implementation that you should use.

Answer (score 1):

what about org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload

Answer (score 0):

It would have preferable if they had deprecated it first with a note to use @MultipartConfig